# How to restrict user not allow below 18+ using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an input field with datepicker. When I select a date from datepicker then date look like `07/03/2019`. Now, I simply calculate age according to the selected date and it gives correct age but problem is that when I select age from datepicker it shows `allowed` message while user below `18` or more. So, How can I restrict user that he/she not allowed below 18+?

code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#register").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if($("#t_c").is(":checked"))
            {
                var date= $("#dob").val();
                var d=new Date(date.split("/").reverse().join("-"));
                var dd=d.getDate();
                var mm=d.getMonth()+1;
                var yy=d.getFullYear();
                var age_date = yy+"/"+mm+"/"+dd;
                var birthdate = new Date(age_date);
                var cur = new Date();
                var diff = cur-birthdate;
                var age = Math.floor(diff/31536000000);

                if(age<=18)
                {
                    alert("allowed");
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("not allowed");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $("#ch").html("<p style='color:red;font-size:12px;'>Please read and then check Terms & Condition</p>");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your if/else block is backwards. It’s showing allowed if they’re 18 or below. Change <= to >=

Comment: Change <= to >= in your if/else

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it should be greater than instead less than symbol

```
if(age>=18)
```

Answer (score 4):

You're making it a tad overly complex. You create two dates for the birthday, and then extract all the values and perform a mathematical operation.

Instead, you can create two objects and compare them with eachother: One with the date of birth, and another one with the current date. Then subtract 18 years from the date-object for today, and compare them!

```js
var // date = $("#dob").val(), // commented out for demo purposes
    date = '07/01/2011',
    d = new Date(date.split("/").reverse().join("-"))
cur = new Date();

cur.setYear(cur.getFullYear() - 18);
if (cur <= d) {
    alert("Allowed");
} else {
    alert("Not allowed");
}
```

**Beware**
The format `07/03/2019` is `MM/DD/YYYY` (I'm assuming? Given that today is July 3rd), but when you do `date.split("/").reverse().join("-")` where `date` is `07/03/2019`, the result is March 7th! The only format that is not ambiguous is `YYYY-MM-DD`, so you should use that if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Check this it is working

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

                var date= "07/03/2019"/*$("#dob").val()*/;
                var d=new Date(date.split("/").reverse().join("-"));
                var dd=d.getDate();
                var mm=d.getMonth()+1;
                var yy=d.getFullYear();
                var age_date = yy+"/"+mm+"/"+dd;
                var birthdate = new Date(age_date);
                var cur = new Date();
                var diff = cur-birthdate;
                var age = Math.floor(diff/31536000000);

                if(age>=18)
                {
                    alert("allowed");
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("not allowed");
                }
    });
</script>
```